# No static content on Moin wiki with lighttpd/FastCGI

Tags: raspberry-pi, lighttpd, moinmoin

I have installed **MoinMoin** wiki on a Raspberry Pi 4 with **lighttpd** using **FastCGI** following mostly this guide:
https://kia.jimmynguyen.co.nz/python/moin/wiki/lighttpd/2020/10/31/moin-wiki-installation-with-lighttpd.html

The problem is that it does not display any of moin static files, so it looks like this:
[image]

I am kind of lost and don't know what to look for, so any help will be gold!

---

I also have Pi-hole running on the same RPi.

I have installed moin with `--prefix=/usr/local` and my wiki instance is at `/opt/wiki`.

All static files are at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/web/static/htdocs/`

My `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` looks like this:

```
    server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_accesslog",
    "mod_auth",
    "mod_expire",
    "mod_redirect",
    "mod_setenv",
    "mod_rewrite",
    "mod_fastcgi"
    )
    
    server.document-root        = "/var/www/html"
    server.error-handler-404    = "/pihole/index.php"
    server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
    server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error-pihole.log"
    server.pid-file             = "/run/lighttpd.pid"
    server.username             = "www-data"
    server.groupname            = "www-data"
    
    ...
    ...
    ...
    
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/wiki/" {
        fastcgi.server += ( "/" =>
            ((
                "socket" => "/tmp/moin.socket",
                "min-procs" => 1,
                "max-procs" => 2,
                "check-local" => "disable",
                "bin-path" => "/opt/wiki/moin.fcgi",
                "fix-root-scriptname" => "enable"
            ))
        )
        alias.url += ( "/moin_static1911" => "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/web/static/htdocs/")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investing more time in this subject I followed the [`HelpOnConfiguration/IntegratingWithLighttpd`](https://moinmo.in/HelpOnConfiguration/IntegratingWithLighttpd) advice:

> Lighttpd 1.4
>
> MoinMoin is listening in FastCGI mode on port 22000.
>
> ```
>   $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/wiki" {
>     fastcgi.server =  ("/wiki" => ( "mywiki" =>
>       ( "host" => "127.0.0.1",
>         "port" => 22000,
>         "check-local" => "disable",
>         "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable" )
>       ))   }
> ```

Also, 'alias.url' should not be inside wiki condition and I moved my code to 'external.conf'.

The result:

```
# Add FastCGI module
server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi",
                    "mod_alias"
                  )

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/wiki" {
    fastcgi.server +=  ("/wiki" => ( "mywiki" =>
      ( "socket" => "/tmp/moin.socket",
        "min-procs" => 1,
        "max-procs" => 2,
        "check-local" => "disable",
        "bin-path" => "/opt/wiki/moin.fcgi"
      )
    ))
}
alias.url += ( "/moin_static1911" => "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/web/static/htdocs/")
```